# What prohibits fundamental fermions transforming like the $6$ and $6^*$ IRR's of $SU(3)$?

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, group-representations

The lowest IRRs of SU(3) are 3,3* (the fundamental reps), 6,6*, and 8 (the adjoint rep).  The quark fields are chosen to transform as 3, 3*, and the gluons as 8 under SU(3), but there is no fundamental particle type (non-composite) transforming as 6, 6*.  Is there a *theoretical* reason that rules out such fields in the QCD Lagrangian?  (This question comes to mind in the spirit of the SM principle that "whatever is not explicitly prohibited in the Lagrangian is required." That principle gives rise to the 'Strong CP problem' in QCD, and is the only reason, so far as I know, that people believe there to be such a problem.)

Comment: Actually, the fact that the fermions are chosen to transform under the fundamental representation and gauge invariance force the gauge fields to transform under the adjoint representation. You can see this by defining the usual gauge covariant derivative and then demanding gauge invariance of the action functional. This immediately yields that the gauge field must transform according to the irreducible representation. So you can say that the only assumption is that fermions transform under the fundamental representations.

Comment: Agreed.  Either requiring gauge invariance or defining vector bosons to transform as the adjoint seem to me to just be two sides of the same coin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. Theoretically, color sextet quarks are a [routine beyond-the-SM speculation](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.72.036007). Experimentally, they don't seem to be around, but model-builders hope they will be found one day.

Your "principle", however, is misconstrued. It is simply not true that every theoretically consistent notion *must* be necessarily realized in nature.

The strong CP violating term is a grossly different kettle of fish: it has all the reps, states,  and symmetries known to be already present, and experience with the dynamical and renormalization features of QCD indicates "unprotected symmetry terms" normally emerge. People are speculating as to how it would appear or not, and why it should be partially or fully insignificant. Again, breaths are being held in expectation of experimental input.

Comment: Wouldn’t having so many über-quarks with twice the usual color charge wreak havoc on the running coupling constant?  Of course, you might dispense with a few heavy flavors, but God might not agree to that.

Comment: Sure, the model-builders have to negotiate narrow logical cave passages, and have, in their voluminous efforts. Heavy scales, few species only, you name it. I was not meaning to endorse their efforts or to intercede to the deity and myself  on their behalf... The question did not appear to stress realism.

Comment: Thanks Cosmas,  very helpful.   Yes, I don't personally subscribe to that principle in that form but had received the impression that some in the field do.   I get your point that the Strong CP situation is much less of a stretch than quark sextets.  The speculation began in earnest with the Axion field hypothesis of Peccei and Quinn in the 70's if I'm not mistaken, with plenty of activity since then.  The lack of any experimental confirmation so far seems to make it an increasingly remote possibility.

Comment: Yes, quite a stretch, but as long as it encourages people to produce tighter experimental bounds...